# bootstrap_flash to display model error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Rails 4.0 and the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem which displays notices with `bootstrap_flash` above the `yield` statement.

One way I put errors in the errors collection is this:

```
if there_is_an_error
  msg = "You have an error here..."
  self.errors.add(:base, msg)
end
```

This should work because I display inline errors next to specific items, so I have no problem with that as far as I know. But I want to display validation errors *at the top* of the form as well sometimes.

What's the best way to display the validation error messages above the form, at the top, especially when using bootstrap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do it via flash, which acts like a hash - flash[:danger], flash[:success] etc:

In controller relevant to the form use *flash[]* before redirect_to (*flash.now[]* before render)

```
flash[:success] = "Signup passed successful"
```

and iterate over flash hash in application.html.erb (layout)

```
<div class="container">
  ...
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
  <% end %>
  ...

  <%= yield %>
  ...
</div>
```

Note that you better use standard bootstrap :key (:sucess, :danger etc) for proper automagic formatting
[Alerts in Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts)

P.S. I personally use Bootstrap 3 gem bootstrap-sass by thomas-mcdonald, but approach should work for you too. Bootstrap 2 uses :error instead of :danger and .alert-block instead .alert

Comment: You gave me a very thorough and complete answer. Worked straight out of the box! I just wonder why it's not displaying these errors by default and I have to do flash.now[] myself.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there bootstrap_flash is designed to work with Rails' flash method. It can be configured to do what you want, including targeting a particular container to display in.

As far as validation goes it does not support it out of the box as many users were implementing their own solutions, typically client-side using ajax to get the errors from the server. We didn't get much consensus on what the right approach would be, so we left it out since other libraries are good at it.